# How to animate UITextField while reducing width dynamically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am creating an application in which I am showing two textfields at login page. In that if user enters incorrect input then it will show Cross symbol in front of the `textfields`. For showing this symbol I am reducing `width` of `UITextField`. I want to do some animation while reducing the `width`. I have done the following :

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 0.1
animation.repeatCount = 1
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(textFieldEmail.center.x - 5, textFieldEmail.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(textFieldEmail.center.x + 5, textFieldEmail.center.y))
        textFieldEmail.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")

self.imageViewCrossPassword.hidden = false
self.passwordRightMarginContraint.constant = 25
```

The above code is applying shake animation for the same. But I want something different which I can apply to only right side of `UITextField`. Suggestions are always appreciated. :-)

Comment: Would you show us the interface builder image or some kind of pictures showing the layout?? I cannot understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: what are u trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a width constraint on `textFieldEmail` and animate it's change with the code like this

```
self.emailWidthConstraint.constant = self.textFieldEmail.bounds.size.width + 5;
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0, options:.Autoreverse, animations: { () -> Void in

    self.textFieldEmail.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :-)